# URL Hacking is not working for all Record Types

Tags: urlhacking

I have implemented URL Hacking for Opportunity Object on New Opportunity creation from Account record(to pre-populate 'Opportunity Name' standard field with 'Account Name'). We actually have 3 Record Types on Account and URL hack works for only one Record Type, for other 2 Record Types, it's not pre-populating 'Opportunity Name'.(opp4 is working, opp3 is not)

/006/e?retURL=/{!Account.Id}&opp3={!Account.Name}&opp4={!Account.Name}

Comment: Which field is not working? opp3 or opp4?

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: Do the users where it's not working have permissions to use the record type?

Comment: I just tried your use case and it's working for me. Are you sure you are calling the right button from the other record types? Because when you create a new record type of Account, you have to choose which page layout you want to apply.

Comment: Oops that's where i lost track. I forgot to change button mapping in other Page layouts and was expecting mistake to be in URL. Thanks for point it out. You can add it as Answer.

Comment: No problem. That was just an error of inattention. You can answer your own question if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is fixed after changing 'New' button mapping in all the associated page layouts of all Record Types.!!

Answer (score 2):

FYI, you need to url encode the account name field because if there is a space in the name the link will not work and you'll be debugging forever before you realize it. This post has some good thoughts on how to do it.  [Proper urlencoding of spaces in formulas syntax](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4074/proper-urlencoding-of-spaces-in-formulas-syntax)

Comment: For now, it's working even for Account Names with spaces. And in that link I read that, 'Salesforce URL Encodes the final output from the custom link'. So is it still required to explicitly URLEncode it? (The link encoding is set to 'UTF-8)

Comment: When I've done URL hack links in the past I've been burned a couple of times where a space in the name breaks the link. I so I wanted to let you know through my experiences, it's tough to troubleshoot because I would not think about it looking at everything else to see why the field is not populated.  In this case I would do a test with a space in the name. Opp3 would get populated but opp4 shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I will consider this point. And fyi, when I did testing with Account names with Spaces, it's working fine for both oop3 & opp4.